# Entity framework: Relation Error

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I was trying to optimize the performance for my site so i followed [these rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc853327.aspx) 
while doing the point about Generating views on compile time i had to create `.edmx` file, after creating this file and follow all the steps I'm facing this issue:

```
Schema specified is not valid. Errors: 
The property for the relationship 'FK_dbo_X_dbo_Y_x_id' contains a Role 'X' has a type 'Site.Models.X' that is not valid for a relationship End. Change the End Role to an EntityType.
```

for every relation i have.

can anyone tell me how can i fix this error?

**Update :**

How i define my relations

in model :

```
    [ForeignKey("foreign_id")]
    public EntityCollection<MyClass> relation_obj { get; set; }
```

in DbContext:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<X>().HasMany(m => m.relation_obj );
```

The relation assembly :

```
[assembly: EdmRelationshipAttribute("DBModel", "FK_dbo_X_dbo_Y_x_id", "X", System.Data.Metadata.Edm.RelationshipMultiplicity.One, typeof(Site.Models.X), "Y", System.Data.Metadata.Edm.RelationshipMultiplicity.Many, typeof(Site.Models.Y), true)]
```

Comment: Could you show code with your optimizations?

Comment: I've added a new `edmx` file so it automatically created new models for every table i have, so i deleted the model and modified the designer and the assembly refs to use the old models like the following : `[assembly: EdmRelationshipAttribute("DBModel", "FK_dbo_X_dbo_Y_restaurant_id", "X", System.Data.Metadata.Edm.RelationshipMultiplicity.One, typeof(Site.Models.X), "Y", System.Data.Metadata.Edm.RelationshipMultiplicity.Many, typeof(RestaurantApp.Models.Y), true)]`  and added the pre-build script like they said here: `http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896240.aspx`

Comment: Mr. @KirillBestemyanov if you need any other peace of information please tell me, your help will be very appreciated !

Comment: Is Site.Models.X and Site.Models.Y EntityFramework generated classes or your defined classes?

Comment: My own classes, the old models i used to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you define as navigation properties classes that has not mapping to database (your own defined classes). Don't do it. Entity framework cannot work with such navigation properties. You can read more about navigation properties [here](http://blog.staticvoid.co.nz/2012/7/17/entity_framework-navigation_property_basics_with_code_first).

Problem is here:

```
[assembly: EdmRelationshipAttribute("DBModel", "FK_dbo_X_dbo_Y_x_id", "X", System.Data.Metadata.Edm.RelationshipMultiplicity.One, typeof(Site.Models.X), "Y", System.Data.Metadata.Edm.RelationshipMultiplicity.Many, typeof(Site.Models.Y), true)]
```

From MSDN:

"

```
public EdmRelationshipAttribute(
    string relationshipNamespaceName,
    string relationshipName,
    string role1Name,
    RelationshipMultiplicity role1Multiplicity,
    Type role1Type,
    string role2Name,
    RelationshipMultiplicity role2Multiplicity,
    Type role2Type
)
```

Parameters

relationshipNamespaceName
    Type: System.String
    The name of the namespace for the association in which this entity participates.

relationshipName
    Type: System.String
    The name of a relationship in which this entity participates.

role1Name
    Type: System.String
    Name of the role for the type at one end of the association.

role1Multiplicity
    Type: System.Data.Metadata.Edm.RelationshipMultiplicity
    A value of RelationshipMultiplicity that indicates the multiplicity at one end of the association, such as one or many.

role1Type
    Type: System.Type
    The type of the **entity** at one end of the association.

role2Name
    Type: System.String
    Name of the role for the type at the other end of the association.

role2Multiplicity
    Type: System.Data.Metadata.Edm.RelationshipMultiplicity
    A value of RelationshipMultiplicity that indicates the multiplicity at the other end of the association, such as one or many.

role2Type
    Type: System.Type
    The type of the **entity** at the other end of the association.
"

So role1Type and role2Type should be entities. Not your own defined classes.

Comment: Sir, I think that i didn't get your point very well, my navigators are mapped to the database through `DbContext`  just like the following :`modelBuilder.Entity<X>().HasMany(m => m.relation_obj );` and it was working previously. Sir, I really appreciate your help. thanks alot!

Comment: Here is Site.Models.Y and Site.Models.X that is not EF classes:[assembly: EdmRelationshipAttribute("DBModel", "FK_dbo_X_dbo_Y_x_id", "X", System.Data.Metadata.Edm.RelationshipMultiplicity.One, typeof(Site.Models.X), "Y", System.Data.Metadata.Edm.RelationshipMultiplicity.Many, typeof(Site.Models.Y), true)]